# Why do I need root privileges to run GDB?

Tags: macos, netbeans, gdb, root, privileges

When I start GDB from the command line I have no problems. But when I start debugging a programs from NetBeans (C++), I get this message:

**"Type the name and password of a user in the "Developer Tools" group to allow Developer Tools Access to make changes."**

My user is already in the "Developer Tools" group, but this fact seems to be ignored.

With the root password it lets me debug, but I would not debug with the root account!

I checked the GDB executable and path, and they all grant executable permissions to everyone.

Any idea?
Thank you!

*Platform:*
MacOS X 10.6.6
NetBeans 6.9.1
GCC 4.2
GDB 6.3.50-20050815

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you will find the answer over here: [Stop "developer tools access needs to take control of another process for debugging to continue" alert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9132826/stop-developer-tools-access-needs-to-take-control-of-another-process-for-debugg)

Basically, you can reinstall Xcode or fix the authorization database.

Answer (score 3):

No, you shouldn't need root privileges to run GDB. Does your software need to run as root? If your software runs as root GDB will also need to be run as root.

What happens if you run GDB on the command line?

Comment: My software does not need root privileges. From the command line, GDB runs with no problems.