# Stop "developer tools access needs to take control of another process for debugging to continue" alert

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, osx-lion

I recently upgraded to 10.7.3, and when I try to debug my iOS project in the simulator for the first time after logging in, I'm prompted with the following two alerts:

[image: Developer Tools Access needs to take control of another process for debugging to continue. Type your password to allow this.]

[image: gdb-i386-apple-darwin needs to take control of another process for debugging to continue. Type your password to allow this.]

My user is an admin user.  I never saw these alerts before.  How do I get them to stop?

**EDIT**

I've verified that I'm a member of the `_developer` group using `id -a`.

Comment: I believe you need to add yourself to the `_developer` group like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1837889/authorize-a-non-admin-developer-in-xcode-mac-os but if you're already part of the `_developer` group (as I am) then I'm not sure what's changed.  I know the `/etc/authorization` file has changed in 10.7.3, and a few tests show that I can eliminate some of the prompts by editing that to always `allow` debug, but with default rules it seems to fail the `_developer` group test. :( I'm noting what I've found so someone else might dig up more details and make more sense of what broke.

Comment: lame that this was closed.

Comment: Not sure why this was too localized; it's a duplicate of the question (with answer) found here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11416025/2063546

Comment: This was asked first. The other is the duplicate.

Answer (score 226, accepted):

There's a much simpler solution for this. Try running the following command:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/DevToolsSecurity --enable
```

**--EDIT--**

If you're on Ventura, see [Mark's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74489896/9636)

Comment: Thank you! This is great. The man page for `DevToolsSecurity` explains exactly what's going on.

Comment: Worked for me, but why the heck did Apple add this barrier ?  You upgrade from a working version of XCode, and immediately find yourself having to Google their strange error messages, trying to find out how to continue using XCode.  Terrible service.

Comment: Didn't work for me either: `Developer mode is already enabled.`

Comment: This worked for me with Xcode 8 on an iMac running a TeamCity agent on Mac OS Sierra.

Comment: Apple is garbage. I also want to keep it disabled, yet I still have to put in Admin??

Comment: Worked for me with 10.2. BTW, this started popping up everytime since 10.2, not with the previous XCode versions.

Comment: Doesn't work with Eclipse CDT with GDB debugger. `Developer mode is already enabled.`

Answer (score 20):

enable develoer mode:
In Terminal run this:
DevToolsSecurity -enable

Comment: Just running 'DevToolsSecurity' command enables it by default. Passing -enable argument is not required

Comment: Doesn't work with Eclipse CDT with GDB debugger. `Developer mode is already enabled.`

Answer (score 12):

Per Zev Eisenberg's answer, reinstalling Xcode 4.2.1 worked.  However, it might be easier to just patch the `/etc/authorization` file with the following diff.

```
        <key>system.privilege.taskport.debug</key> 
        <dict>
            <key>allow-root</key>
            <false/>
            <key>class</key>
-           <string>user</string>
+           <string>rule</string>
            <key>comment</key>
            <string>For use by Apple.  WARNING: administrators are advised
             not to modify this right.</string>
            <key>default-button</key>
            <dict>
            ...
            </dict>
            <key>default-prompt</key>
            <dict>
            ...
            </dict>
-           <key>group</key>
-           <string>_developer</string>
            <key>shared</key>
            <true/>
-           <key>timeout</key>
-           <integer>36000</integer>
+           <key>k-of-n</key>
+           <integer>1</integer>
+           <key>rule</key>
+           <array>
+               <string>is-admin</string>
+               <string>is-developer</string>
+               <string>authenticate-developer</string>
+           </array>
        </dict>
```

Comment: I had done the same thing as above. The problem now is that I am not able to get internet wifi. I am not sure how this is happening.

Comment: I've tried DevSecurityTools, adding myself to the _developer group and these modifications. I'm still being prompted to give access. So far, I've not been able to find anything that removes the prompt.

Comment: Changing system.privilege.taskport by executing ```security authorizationdb write system.privilege.taskport allow``` made my password prompts to disappear

Answer (score 9):

Reinstalling Xcode 4.2.1 after upgrading to 10.7.3 seems to have fixed it for me.

Comment: We will have to this once again when either Mac OS 10.8 or iOS 5.1 launch. Word is they are making the Xcode app an actual .app for ease of updating through App Store.

Comment: Xcode 4.3 is already delivered in this manner. I haven't had this password issue since installing it.

Answer (score 9):

I modified the rule for `system.privilege.taskport` and the alert doesn't show up anymore.

1. Open the file `/etc/authorization`.
2. Find the rule `system.privilege.taskport`. Under the line `<key>class</key>`, change `<string>rule</string>` to `<string>allow</string>`

Comment: Posting a diff is a little nicer.

Comment: I've tried all the other suggestions and this is the only one that worked. Thanks.

Comment: This might work but it might also open up a security hole in your sandbox. I am a bit wary.

Comment: Thanks! But /etc/authorization is deprecated on the mavericks. Do you know what should I use now?

Comment: Like I commented above, it also works by executing ```security authorizationdb write system.privilege.taskport allow``` in the command line.

Comment: I don't even have that file: `/etc/authorization: No such file or directory`. I am not using XCode, but Eclipse CDT with GDB debuuger, and I am having the same problems. Any idea?

Answer (score 9):

I had same issue with my mac 10.12.5 & Xcode9
Run this command :

```
sudo security authorizationdb write system.privilege.taskport allow
```

Then enter your password.. Check if it still prompt you.
Good luck..

Comment: This helped with Eclipse CDT. Thanks.

Comment: worked on macOS 12.6 monterey.

Answer (score 8):

I'm on macOS Ventura and receive

[image]

### TL;DR

`sudo dscl . append /Groups/_developer GroupMembership <username>`

As per https://stackoverflow.com/a/1837935/5506988

### What was tried

`sudo /usr/sbin/DevToolsSecurity --enable` says it's already enabled.

After entering my username and password, it works but then I have to do this every time I launch the debugger.

If I run `sudo security authorizationdb write system.privilege.taskport allow` it prevents the prompt **but only until the next restart.**

I tried following the existing answers that ask you to update `/etc/authorization` - which has been deprecated since macOS mavericks and is now `/System/Library/Security/authorization.plist` but I couldn't edit this file (I even tried [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/68646/how-do-i-unlock-a-plist-file-so-that-i-can-change-it)) but since my `$USER` isn't an owner of the file so I can't force overwrite it even with sudo.

I tried

```
sudo /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :rights:system.privilege.taskport:class allow" authorization.plist
```

But of course, the same applies but instead this fails silently.

If I run `id -a` it returns `204(_developer)` so I am part of the developer group even before running the `dcsl` command

What fixed it for me was

```
sudo dscl . append /Groups/_developer GroupMembership <username>
```

Comment: Didn't seem to work for me on Ventura.

Comment: @LordZsolt did you try to run `sudo /usr/sbin/DevToolsSecurity --enable` first then dscl

Answer (score 2):

I just turned debugging off in (edit scheme) -> uncheck debug executable.
But I also do all of my debugging on another console, so if you are developing and need the debugger then it wont help. I only have this issue with an old version of Xcode 8.2.1 since I am running the code on an old Mac using El Capitan.

Newer mac and Xcode version 10 doesn't seem to have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Something has been modified on file /etc/authorization, I've a Lion without v10.7.3 and it has the following code

Lines 5807-5814

```
    <key>k-of-n</key>
    <integer>1</integer>
    <key>rule</key>
    <array>
        <string>is-admin</string>
        <string>is-developer</string>
        <string>authenticate-developer</string>
    </array>
```

After the update the file contains many modification due to new language supported but the lines corresponding to debugging authorization differ from the lines shown above in

Lines 7675-7676

```
    <key>group</key>
    <string>_developer</string>
```

I can't apply these differences to my 10.7.3 Lion installation because it's a production machine and I can't risk to corrupt it

I've all necessasy permission as shown from command `id -a`

```
uid=501(dave) gid=20(staff) groups=20(staff),
401(com.apple.access_screensharing),
402(com.apple.sharepoint.group.1),
12(everyone),
33(_appstore),
61(localaccounts),
79(_appserverusr),
80(admin),
81(_appserveradm),
98(_lpadmin),
100(_lpoperator),
204(_developer)
```

Answer (score -4):

**no need code. no need reinstall xcode. Do these steps:**

1.close xcode.

2.open Keychain access.

3.double click your Keychain(the key icon which create from keychain.p12)

4.go to access control panel(name maybe not right)

5.enable all app access this.

6.save.

7.run your xcode project.

8.it works well.