# instruments + UIAutomation from shell script

Tags: ios, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation, xcode-instruments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to remove the authorization prompt from command-line instances of Instruments (XCode)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9476131/is-there-a-way-to-remove-the-authorization-prompt-from-command-line-instances-of)

I've been stuck building a jenkins job to automatically run my UIAutomation script now ALL day. One by one I've worked through all the issues with doing this (jenkins running as a daemon by default, lots more) and I have one left. The 'instruments' command will ask for permission to listen to a process or something (I forget the exact wording) and since this requires a prompt of the user/pass it kills my script with error:

> Failed to authorize rights (0x2) with status: -60007

This is my last hurdle to getting this working and I've tried:

> echo "user\npassword" | instruments ....

but this doesn't seem to feed these prompted values in at all. Still fails with the same error. How do I run instruments or modify some file somewhere so it won't prompt for this?

Thankyou!

Comment: no we gave up and started using a plugged in device

Comment: I see. Damn it. So there is no way to do this on the simulator ?

Comment: We had 2 developers looking at it full-time for 2 days and we couldn't figure it out:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like something I am going to have to dive into soon myself.

I'd be curious what happens if you add your instruments command to /etc/sudoers and then try to run.  Might avoid the auth prompt you're seeing.

To give it a try:

1. "sudo visudo" in a terminal
2. Add this line (replacing "yourargs" with the rest of your instruments command)

yourUserName      ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/instruments yourargs

Then try running the command the Jenkins agent is trying to run, prefixing it with "sudo", e.g. "sudo instruments ..."

Comment: I'm trying this now - will let you know.

Comment: We ended up giving up on the simulator (even tried sshing into itself) and now just have a device plugged in.