# Remove the authorization prompt from command line instruments (Under mavericks)

Tags: ios, xcode, authorization, osx-mavericks, ios-ui-automation

Similar to this question, except that the authorization database changed formats for mavericks and the old solution doesn't work: [Is there a way to remove the authorization prompt from command-line instances of Instruments (XCode)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9476131/is-there-a-way-to-remove-the-authorization-prompt-from-command-line-instances-of)

The specific use-case being to get ios-driver working to run automated tests: http://ios-driver.github.io/ios-driver/faq.html

The specific prompt is "Instruments wants permission to analyze other processes"

I've tried

```
sudo security authorizationdb write system.privilege.taskport allow
```

and

```
sudo security authorizationdb write system.privilege.taskport is-developer
```

(with the user being in the _developers group) but the prompt is still coming up every time :(

Also tried

```
sudo security authorizationdb write com.apple.dt.instruments.process.analysis allow
```

because that looked related (thinking maybe the name of the required permission changed as well as the way to set it), but still getting the prompt

Comment: Is your user "marked as admin"? I've made the experience, that neither the unlock keychain nor the tasport allow command worked without "being admin". In all other cases I had to confirm the prompt at least once to get it working