# Instruments wants permission to analyze other processes Jenkins

Tags: xcode, swift, jenkins, osx-server, fastlane

So my problem is that on pure swift project (almost :-) ) with test written also in Swift I got this every build. Build is started via Fastlane 1.63. :

```
▸ DTServiceHub: Instruments wants permission to analyze other processes. Please enter an administrator username and password to allow this.
▸ Username (jenkins): Password:
▸ Failed to authorize rights (0x1) with status: -60007.
```

Problem occurs when new command-line-tools and Xcode 7.3 was installed on MacPro with OSX Server. Objective-C project works every time. I've done what was suggested in those threads, didn't work:
[Remove the authorization prompt from command line instruments (Under mavericks)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21285793/remove-the-authorization-prompt-from-command-line-instruments-under-mavericks)
[Is there a way to remove the authorization prompt from command-line instances of Instruments (XCode)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9476131/is-there-a-way-to-remove-the-authorization-prompt-from-command-line-instances-of) and in all other places that I could find. I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: I have started to have the problem after Xcode 7.3 upgrade... any chance you've fix this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I just experienced a similar problem, triggered by Fastlane `scan` command to execute tests.

Following [the discussion on this issue](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/2616) and [this Apple Support discussion](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3780934?start=0&tstart=0) I managed to solve it by **enabling "Developer Mode"** on my CI machine.

```
$ DevToolsSecurity -status
Developer mode is currently disabled.

$ DevToolsSecurity -enable
Developer mode is now enabled.
```

Comment: I have started to have the problem after Xcode 7.3 upgrade... any chance you've fix this?

Comment: Yes, for me running insturments manualy helped, but I've done a lot of thing before that, so I'm not sure if this was it. Also restart Xcode, accept licens via terminal for xCode, restart Jenkins and Mac that is runing as host.

Comment: Any confirmed way of fixing this? I've done all above but still getting the error.

Answer (score -1):

I've got the same problem with Xcode 7.3. I wasn't admin on my Mac (I work on a company network) so the network manager gave me the admin rights and it works... I don't know why :)