# Issue with IOS Instruments running from command line on build machine

Tags: xcode, jenkins, instruments, ios-ui-automation

I've successfully run **IOS UI Automation Instruments** from **command line** on **my local Mac**. When it starts to test, the **simulator** will automatically pop up and then do the stuff.

However, when I SSH to a **build server** (with OSX and xcode, will use Jenkins eventually) and try to do the same thing, it doesn't work well.

Building process is fine, but as long as I run instruments, the terminal will then **hang** there without doing anything. I figure it has something to do with iphone simulator GUI but since it's CLI, I don't know what's going on...

Do you guys have any idea? Thanks!!

Comment: Are you running Jenkins as a logged in user? Since instruments has to launch the simulator you must run jenkins (or whatever CI tool you're using) as a user who is logged in so there is a window manager.

Comment: @JonathanPenn Thanks for getting back. I have a Jenkins server that is not in OSX, so I need to SSH to a OSX build machine to build it and run instruments. So in this case do we still have a window manager here?

Answer (score 1):

[image: Developer Tools Access].

After executing the command from Jenkins through SSH; in most cases you would see a pop up window as in the screen shot. You will have to get past this screen to execute your tests. This post addresses how to get past that issue [Stop "developer tools access needs to take control of another process for debugging to continue" alert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9132826/stop-developer-tools-access-needs-to-take-control-of-another-process-for-debugg)

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue. instruments -w "$DEVICE" were ignoring parameters.
Same with

```
DEVICE_TARGET='iPhone 6 (8.1 Simulator)' cucumber --format json -o test-reports/cucumber-8.1-iphone.json
```

It were ignoring DEVICE_TARGET parameter.

Solved via running Jenkins slave **NOT as a SSH slave** but as the **Slave agent via java web start**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNlPA.png

As i understand this issue is caused by OS X launchagent that managing sshd and performs scope of restrictions for remote users.

**IMPORTANT!** Slave agent should be started from OS X desktop, **not via ssh!** I've connected via VNC and launched slave java web agent on the OS X UI terminal.