# Alert"Developer tools access needs to take control of another process for debugging to continue.Type your password to allow this."

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, ios-simulator, osx-mavericks

I am using OS X Mavericks with Xcode 4.6.3. I am running the app on simulator as i don't have a developer account. Whenever i run the project on simulator it keeps asking me "Developer tools access needs to take control of another process for debugging to continue. Type your password to allow this". The same issue i also experienced on OS X Mountain Lion with Xcode 4.6.2, so its definitely not related to the OS Version or Xcode Version.

I have gone through Stackoverflow's issue related threads,Q&A.
 Thanks

Comment: why does mac always over complicate things

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stop "developer tools access needs to take control of another process for debugging to continue" alert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9132826/stop-developer-tools-access-needs-to-take-control-of-another-process-for-debugg)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The first time you launched XCode, it probably asked you if you wanted to enable Developer Mode on this mac. If you accepted, then it asked you for your password, and you stopped getting this kind of warning.

Chances are good that you declined, and now it has to explicitly ask you for permission every time it tries to do lots of common developer tasks.

Enabling "Developer Mode" has nothing to do with having an actual iOS developer account with Apple, it's merely a loosening of security restrictions on your mac. Effectively you are giving your mac permission to not ask you for a password during common developer tasks.

You can enable developer mode by opening terminal and typing this:

```
DevToolsSecurity -enable
```

It should prompt for your password, then you'll likely have to log out and back in for the setting to take effect.

That should stop the warnings!

**EDIT**

those of you averse to the command line can find similar functionality in the organizer window

Open the Organizer window in XCode (Shift Apple 2) and within the "Devices" tab you'll see "My Mac" listed. You can enable and disable developer mode with the click of a button there.

Comment: the issue was not there 2 days back.as i installed and using Xcode for last 8 to 9 month.thx

Comment: I had to re-enable it on all my machines this past week after upgrading to Mavericks. I think the upgrade just reset it back to NO.

Comment: how to check whether i have enabled developer mode or not using terminals.for checking there must be some command.if u know please it.

Comment: My apologies, I cut and pasted the wrong line from my notes. You want this command:   DevToolsSecurity -enable

Comment: Alternately you can just open the Organizer window in XCode (Shift Apple 2) and within the "Devices" tab you'll see "My Mac" listed. You can enable and disable developer mode with the click of a button there.

Comment: it's woks and Absolutely right way to analyse the problem and come to a solution.this is the right way for development.Buddy please edit your previous answer and mention what u have mention in the comments as that is the actual answer that works for everybody!!!!Thank u very much!!!

Comment: it shows WARNING: Improper use of the sudo command could lead to data loss
or the deletion of important system files. Please double-check your
typing when using sudo. Type "man sudo" for more information. while i am going to type this command sudo /usr/sbin/DevToolsSecurity --enable

Comment: It works as expected on Mac OS 10.8 and older, but on Mac OS 10.9 I have to type password once after reboot. Any idea why? Browsed the Internet for more options, but didn't find anything useful

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9725547/9636

Answer (score 4):

The solution for mavericks is this command :

```
sudo security authorizationdb write system.privilege.taskport allow
```

Based on this post : 
http://www.ama-dev.com/xcode-build-command-line-remove-authorization-prompt-for-uiautomation/

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using older version of Xcode (below 6) type this command on terminal :

```
DevToolsSecurity -enable
```

This will prompt a dialog requesting system password. Enter password and you can see `'Developer mode is now enabled'` log on terminal.

[image: Screenshot 2]

If you are using Xcode 6 (or above) `it will automatically ask for enabling developer mode`. Simply click *'Enable'* to enable developer mode.

[image: Screenshot]