# Alert“Developer tools access needs to take control of another process for debugging to continue.”

Tags: ios, xcode

I am using mac OS X 10.8.5 and Xcode 4.6.3 and Xcode 5.0.2. While I am running my project on iPhone simulator it is giving me the following Alert. [image]

My Developer tool is enabled and also I've tried the following things
**sudo dscl . append /Groups/_developer GroupMembership** 
But it is not working.

Note: I am not using **Admin account**.

Comment: Check this question everything is explained about the same issue 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9132826/stop-developer-tools-access-needs-to-take-control-of-another-process-for-debugg?rq=1

Comment: possible duplicate of [Alert"Developer tools access needs to take control of another process for debugging to continue.Type your password to allow this."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19626856/alertdeveloper-tools-access-needs-to-take-control-of-another-process-for-debugg)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your OS X user name to the _developer group. The following command should work:

```
sudo dscl . append /Groups/<groupname> GroupMembership <username>
```

**Note:** `<group>` means developer group name in your mac. If you confuse about groupname, just rename groupname by knowing `admin user name` as below

```
$ dseditgroup -o edit -u <adminusername> -t user -a <developerusername> NewdevelopergroupName
```

Now you can use `NewdevelopergroupName` as `groupname`.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response , I'll check and get back to you

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution for Mavericks.

Tape this command in terminal :

```
sudo security authorizationdb write system.privilege.taskport allow
```

Based on this post :

http://www.ama-dev.com/xcode-build-command-line-remove-authorization-prompt-for-uiautomation/