# Guest session - Stop "Xcode needs to take control of another process for debugging to continue"

Tags: xcode, swift-playground

I am getting the same prompt as in [Stop "developer tools access needs to take control of another process for debugging to continue" alert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9132826/stop-developer-tools-access-needs-to-take-control-of-another-process-for-debugg)

In that question the answer is to just enable it, for which one needs the computer's admin password.

I am in a computer using the Guest session and don't have the password. I am just trying to use the Playground to test minor things.

Is there a way to stop this warning?
Disable the debugging mode in the Playground, maybe? If so, how does that work?

Thanks!